# The APFS partition on my external hard drive doesn't mount anymore

Tags: hard-drive, catalina, partition, external-disk, data-recovery

I have a WD Elements 1.5Tb external hard drive with two partitions. One is for Windows (that I use with Bootcamp on my mac), the other is for OSX (APFS file system). Usually, OSX can see both WIN and MAC partitions as separate drives, and Windows only see the WIN partition.

Today I plugged my HDD into my Mac, and I only can see the WIN partition anymore (in Finder and on my Desktop). It shows up on Disk Utility with a generic name, two times (As a partition, grayed out, and as a separate disk, uninitialized). I cannot mount them or run S.O.S on it. One is grayed out.
[image: Disk utility on the whole hard drive]

[image: Disk utility on the mac/APFS partition]

[image]

but I still have no ways to even read it. I tried different usb ports, even plugged it into another Mac and got the same results.
It also seems to show up with diskutil but I still cannot do anything with it:
[image]

I also tried Stellar Data Recovery which shows me +64gb of files on it that it can recover, so it's still there, but I cannot afford the 100$ to recover it.

I really need the data that's on this drive, so is there anyway I can repair it myself, or at least recover the data? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "First Aid"?

Comment: Hint: In Disk Utility, the structure of disks is better shown if you turn on this option in the menu bar: Menu -> View -> Show All Devices. My suspicion is that you formatted the XHDD1 partition in Windows and that did something bad to the APFS Container.

Comment: @DarwinOSX Yes, that's what I called "S.O.S" (my system is in french)

Comment: @Gilby Thanks for the tip, I edited my post with new screenshots. I don't think it has to do with it, since I didn't do any formatting on the Windows partition, I didn't even used it or booted windows recently

Comment: The AppleAPFSMedia is very strange appearing as a 'device' when it is clearly  the APFS container on the WD drive.  Try S.O.S on the WD drive (you might need to eject the AppleAPFSMedia first) which will attempt repair of the partitions. It would be wise to backup your XHDD1 partition first if you have another suitable disk. I think it is likely that you won't fix it and will need to use recovery software. I have used Disk Drill - like most recovery products cost about $100.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gilby for your help, I'm currently running a scan with Disk Drill and it looks like it's gonna save most of my data (when they paying Stellar Data Recovery only found a fraction of it). Do you think I can then format my hdd completely and use it again (more wisely this time), or is it a hardware problem and I should just throw it away?

Comment: Well, juste realized Disk Drill is also payed.

Comment: All recovery software requires payment before it will recover files. My guess is that you do not have a hardware problem.  If it were me I would have separate external HDD for Windows and macOS and disconnect the macOS drive when using Windows. And, of course, make sure I have a good backup strategy.